# How to send mobile and desktop requests to different routers?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I would like to be able to do something like this in Express :

```
var mobile = express.Router(),
    desktop = express.Router();

mobile.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // some routing for mobile devices
});

desktop.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // some routing for desktop devices
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var device = new MobileDetect(req.headers['user-agent']);

    if (device.mobile())
        // send request to `mobile` router
    else
        // send request to `desktop` router
});
```

So that the mobile and desktop parts of my game are totally distinct.
However I can't find a way to "send the request to a router", is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have some middleware to detect mobile and redirect ? http://therockncoder.blogspot.co.il/2013/11/mobile-device-detection-and-redirection.html for example.

Comment: Well that implies the mobile part to have a /mobile prefix in every URL, but why not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to invoke those routers with the parameters they expect as middleware:

```
if (device.mobile()) {
  mobile(req, res, next)
} else {
  desktop(req, res, next)
}
```